# Azure Data Factory explicit mapping doesn't work

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that read and copy a Excel file which has no header into a database. For column mapping I use a JSON parameter, which something like this:

```
{
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "mappings": [
        {
            "source": {
                "name": "Prop_0"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "Name"
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "name": "Prop_1"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "ID(Sort)"
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "name": "Prop_2"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "Phone Number(P/O)"
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

My pipeline has worked properly until recently it keep sending me out this message error

```
ErrorCode=MappingColumnNameNotFoundInSourceFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'Prop_1' specified in column mapping cannot be found in 'User.xlsx' source file.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

The pipeline has no update recently and I have try some solutions for this issue:

- If in JSON file I only keep 1 field (which is Prop_0) the pipeline will work but if in JSON mapping has more than 1 columns it will send out the same error
- I manually mapping columns instead of using JSON file, the pipeline will work
- In JSON file, at source setting, if I replace **name** field by **ordinal** field (**name: "Prop_0"** will be replaced with **ordinal: 1**, the pipeline will work

So I don't understand why I get the error if I keep the old setting (JSON file with name field at source setting). I wonder whether there something change in ADF engine or not and how I could resolve this problem.
Thank you so much