# Mapping JSON column not found

Tags: sql-server, excel, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in ADF which has suddenly failed due to being unable to find a column: 'Prop_1'

> ErrorCode=MappingColumnNameNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column name 'Prop_1' is not found in the source table. Please check the column in 'mappings'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'

This is an Excel to SQL copy task and the Excel doc I am working with has no column headers hence passing Prop_X in my mapping JSON (extract below):

```
{
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "typeConversion": true,
    "typeConversionSettings": {
        "culture": "en-gb"
    },
    "mappings": [
        {
            "source": {
                "name": "Prop_0"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "EmployeeID"
            }
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "name": "Prop_1"
            },
            "sink": {
                "name": "Forename"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have manually checked the file via the UI and when trying to import the mapping, ADF returns the ordinal values rather than Prop_X as previously.
[ADF showing ordinal mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfWIe.png)

When I click preview data however, Prop_X is clearly visible:
[Preview Source showing Prop columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQrz3.png)

There is already an unanswered post on this from ~3 months ago ([Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76777519/azure-data-factory-explicit-mapping-doesnt-work)). I can't see anything else on Microsoft and the documentation suggests what I have set up is correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#tabular-source-to-tabular-sink),

> For the delimited text file and excel files without headers, the column are considered as ordinals instead of names in the mapping.

If the file don't have any header, then the mapping should be with ordinals, else it will give the above error. Even if you don't import the schema in mapping, it will give the same error.

**To avoid the error, your mapping needs to be with the ordinals** that means you need to import the schema in copy activity for this kind of files.

**If you want to set the schema dynamically in copy activity mapping** instead of manual schema importing, follow the below steps.

Get the structure array from the target SQL table using Get Meta data activity.

[image]

Start the dynamic mapping like below with string `{"type": "TabularTranslator","mappings":`.

[image]

Now, use a Foreach activity to build the mapping array. Give this expression in the Foreach activity and check the **Sequential**.

```
@range(0,activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount)
```

Inside the ForEach, use append variable activity to an empty and give the below expression.

```
@json(concat('{"source": {"ordinal":"',string(add(item(),1)),'","type": "String"},"sink": {"name": "',activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure[item()].name,'","type": "',activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure[item()].logicalType,'"}}'))
```

[image]

After ForEach, take another set variable activity and concat the total mapping with below expression.

```
@concat(variables('schema'),string(variables('mapping')),',"typeConversion": true,"typeConversionSettings":{"allowDataTruncation": false,"treatBooleanAsNumber": false}}')
```

[image]

This will generate the schema JSON like below for sample.

[image]

Give this variable `final_schema` in the copy activity mapping dynamic content.

```
@json(variables('final_schema'))
```

[image]

Now, debug the pipeline and your excel data will be copied to the SQL table.

**Result**:

[image]

**My pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "final_schema",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "ExcelSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "value": "@json(variables('final_schema'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Excel1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "structure",
                        "columnCount"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Start schema",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(0,activity('Get Metadata1').output.columnCount)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "mapping",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(concat('{\"source\": {\"ordinal\":\"',string(add(item(),1)),'\",\"type\": \"String\"},\"sink\": {\"name\": \"',activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure[item()].name,'\",\"type\": \"',activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure[item()].logicalType,'\"}}'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Start schema",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "schema",
                    "value": "{\"type\": \"TabularTranslator\",\"mappings\":"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "final_schema",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "final_schema",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@concat(variables('schema'),string(variables('mapping')),',\"typeConversion\": true,\"typeConversionSettings\":{\"allowDataTruncation\": false,\"treatBooleanAsNumber\": false}}')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "schema": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "mapping": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "final_schema": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @rakesh-govindula, this has been working as expected for over 18 months, and the ADF's UI also recognises the property values so for it to suddenly, and unexpectedly, fail suggests either the documentation is incorrect, has been updated, or I've somehow stumbled on a workaround that has now been closed off.

I've opened a support ticket with Microsoft who are investigating.

I should have added that the mapping JSON is generated via SQL and I'm now looking into including a condition to handle ordinal/name pairs if this cannot be resolved.

Comment: Ok, if you have any update about this, update here as well.

Comment: Microsoft have confirmed that this is linked to our current SHIR version; the issue can be replicated on 5.32.8600.2 but is fixed in later releases, including the latest release: 5.35.8686.1.